# Ruby on Rails- :symbols, @iVars and "strings" - oh my!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, symbols, instance-variables

New to Rails and trying to get my head around when/why to use `:symbols`, `@ivars` , `"strings"` within the framework.

I think I understand the differences between them conceptually

- only one `:symbol` instance per project
- one `@ivar` per instance
- multiple `"strings"` - as they are created whenever referenced *(?)*

*Feel free to correct me!*

The main confusion comes from understanding the **rules** & **conventions** of what Rails expects - where and WHY?

I'm sure there's an "Ah ha!" moment coming but I haven't had it yet...as it seems pretty arbitrary to me (coming from C/Obj-C).

-thx

Answer (score 21):

The `@instance_variable` is an instance variable. It is usually defined in the controller and accessible in the views.

The `"string"` is a string, like as in any other language.

The `:symbol`, is as you mentioned it's an efficient way of representing names and strings; they are literal values. It is initialized and exists only once during the ruby session. It's not a string, since you don't have access to String methods; it's a Symbol. On top of that, it's immutable. For those reasons, it becomes very handy in representing keys in hashs. Rails methods uses hashes, thus, you find symbols a bit everywhere in Rails.

Comment: Ah, the relation between hashes & `:symbols` makes sense (+1). Still i seem to see strings & symbols & ivars passed to methods somewhat interchangeably?!? Maybe the pattern will become clear as I work through this...

Answer (score 4):

Instance variables are pretty straightforward: they track properties/values of a particular instance, so you use them when you the values will vary across instances.

Symbols vs. strings are a bit more arbitrary. Symbols are generally used for *constant* values, in much the same way that a language such as C would use enums; Ruby doesn't have enums, so symbols are often used to fill that gap. Strings are used for more varied pieces of text that won't be used as a flag or similar constant.

Answer (score 4):

Symbols are kind of like pointers (not in the C-ish way, but in C-ish thinking, they point). Well, you use symbols when you are manipulating properties. They are one of the great benefits of dynamic typing if you'd ask me. (For potential voters I do not mean any harm, I do know that they are not pointers, but it felt 'ah-ha!' for me).

```
:action => "index"
```

Instance variables are needed when you fetch data from your model and you want to use them across your views (inside your controller method).

```
def my_controller_method
@myposts = Post.find(:all)
end

# inside view
<% for @myposts do |m| %>
<i><%= m.title %></i>
<% end %>
```

Just a heads up, the rules and conventions kinda change rapidly (as I discovered on my Rails journey) quite a lot per version. Having the right guide with the right Rails helps. Good luck with coding!

Comment: joining the #rubyonrails on freenode helps a lot, it surely did help me to understand Rails quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables don't really belong in the same list as strings and symbols. Strings and Symbols are *types of classes* whereas instance variables are a *type of variable*. So instance variables (`@var`) are just a way to store a value between methods of one instance of one class:

```
class Calculator
  @counter = 0

  def inc
    @counter += 1
  end

  def dec
    @counter -= 1
  end
end
```

[Here](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2007/11/26/akitaonrails-on-ruby-symbols/) is a good article on the distinction between symbols and strings.

Answer (score -1):

The Rails controller access the rails database through Models by ORM (Object Relation Mapping)i.e Model class will mapped to its corresponding table and Objects are directly mapped to rows in the table.In order to get the results for a given user query,the instance variable (@instance_variable) is the perfect choice to deal with it.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question?